# AWS EC2 Instance Stops Responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

EC2 instance stops responding with `Instance reachability check failed` status every few days. The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It works again after an instance reboot.

Is there any way I can find the exact issue?

Comment: In my experience you're running out of memory.  What runs on the EC2?

Comment: Have this issue was solved? 

I need help on same AWS issue. Actual when I try to connect to instance it won't get connected and all my server frontend and backend is stopped(no response from server). Thus when I stop and start the instance again it start working again, later next day same. but if I see my instance status on AWS console dashboard it shows Running